# Navigation Bar Formatting in Ex-Navigator (ExponentJS)

Tags: ios, react-native, navigationbar

I'm trying to format the bottom border of the ExponentJS Ex-Navigator in React Native.  I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to hide the bottom border from the NavigationBar.

Comment: Could you provide some reproduction steps or share repo (reduced to just the issue in case it's a big project)?

Comment: Hi. After diving into the node_modules, I was able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No Need to Overwrite Hard-Coded Styles in Library

You can just apply a style in the `ExNavigator` component, like so:

```
<ExNavigator
  navigationBarStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}
  ...
  />
```

You can also set the `backgroundColor` and the `borderBottomWidth` here as well.

Comment: where did you do that?

Comment: @Ricbermo This happens at your entrance file where you initially setup `<ExNavigator...`

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

To alter the style of the NavigatorNavigationBar, look in ./node-modules/@exponent/react-native-navigator/ExNavigatorStyles.js

The bar stylesheet object entry enables you to style the bar itself in the ExNavigator

```
bar: {
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    borderBottomColor: '#b2b2b2',
    borderBottomWidth: Layout.pixel,
},
```

For my question, I set the borderBottomColor to 'transparent' and am now good to go.

```
bar: {
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomWidth: Layout.pixel,
},
```